# How to interpret the "code" passed to CallNextHookEx

Tags: winapi, hook

I'm wondering which values the 2nd parameter (code) of the CallNextHookEx function may take, Unfortunately the MSDN documentation is quite vague about that parameter:

> The hook code passed to the current hook procedure. The next hook procedure uses this code  to determine how to process the hook information.

I assume the values the code parameter may take are defined somwhere among the "[Hook Structures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468844%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)"

How can I interpret the values correctly?

Am I allowed to manipulate that value or am I expected to just pass the code as I originally received it?

Comment: Just pass the nCode that was passed to you in your callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value is explained in the documentation of the hook procedure.

e.g. `GetMsgProc`:

> Specifies whether the hook procedure must process the message. If code
>   is `HC_ACTION`, the hook procedure must process the message. If code is
>   less than zero, the hook procedure must pass the message to the
>   CallNextHookEx function without further processing and should return
>   the value returned by CallNextHookEx.

The documentation for the `code` parameter is similar to the above for most (all?) procedures.

That means that you should process only calls for which `code` is equal to `HC_ACTION`. Otherwise, you should just call `CallNextHookEx` with original parameters, and return the result.